# Joins Using QueryDsl and Boolean Expression

Tags: spring-boot, querydsl, boolean-expression

Need a help regarding QueryDsl using BooleanExpression. Find the requirement below.

1. I have Enquiry and Followup table. OneToMany mapping in between them. 1 Enquiry having many followup.
2. Suppose i have 5 enquiries. for each enquiry i have 3 followup.
3. Expectation is ..i need last record of followup for each enquiry.

Please find the different ways i have tried.

```
QBuyerFollowUp qBuyerfollowup = QBuyerFollowUp.buyerFollowUp;
ListPath<BuyerFollowUp, QBuyerFollowUp> followUpList = qBuyerEnquiry.followUpList;
```

1. ```
   BooleanExpression expression = commonExpression.and(new JPAQuery<>().select(qBuyerfollowup.nextDate).from(qBuyerfollowup)
                       .where(qBuyerfollowup.eq(followUpList.any()))
                       .orderBy(qBuyerfollowup.followUpId.desc()).limit(1).eq(new Date());
   ```

   please ignore commonExpression which is an another expression.

   > Error: Subquery returns more than 1 row
2. ```
   BooleanExpression  expression = followUpList.any().followUpId.in(new JPAQuery<QBuyerFollowUp>().select(qBuyerfollowup.followUpId.max())
                       .from(qBuyerfollowup).groupBy(qBuyerfollowup.buyerEnquiry.id)
                       .having(qBuyerfollowup.nextDate.eq(dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new Date())))));
   ```

   > Error: unknown column nextDate.

   Here generated query is:

   ```
   select count(buyerenqui0_.id) as col_0_0_ from buyer_enquiry buyerenqui0_ where 
   buyerenqui0_.assigned_to= 79 and 
   (buyerenqui0_.created_at between "2020-05-01 00:00:00" and "2020-05-31 23:59:59") and buyerenqui0_.enq_status<> "Dropped" and  
   not ( not (exists (select followupli1_.id from buyer_followup followupli1_ where buyerenqui0_.id=followupli1_.buyer_enquiry_id))) 
   and (exists (select 1 from buyer_followup followupli2_ where buyerenqui0_.id=followupli2_.buyer_enquiry_id and 
   (followupli2_.id in (select max(a.id) from buyer_followup a group by a.buyer_enquiry_id having date(a.next_date)=date(now())))));
   ```

   solution: If will remove alias name 'a'  from this query

   ```
   select max(a.id) from buyer_followup a group by a.buyer_enquiry_id having date(a.next_date)=date(now())))
   ```

   it is working fine. 
   But we don't have any control on this because alias name is generated by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You can't join subqueries in JPQL, but you can project them, which should be sufficient in this case:

```
QInquiry inquiry = QInquiry.inquiry;
QFollowup followup = QFollowup.followup;

Map<Inquiry, Followup> results = query().from(inquiry)
    .transform(GroupBy.groupBy(inquiry).as(query().from(followup)
        .where(followup.inquiry.eq(inquiry)
        .orderBy(followup.id.desc())
        .limit(1)))
```